# How to get all the names of the tables involved in a sql query?

Tags: php, sql

For example:

I have this query:

```
SELECT first_name
FROM users
    INNER JOIN roles ON roles.id = users.id_roles
WHERE roles.name = 'admin';
```

I need an `Array` with the name of the tables used in the query,like that:

```
['users','roles'];
```

Comment: Howyou did this in php? show your code please?

Comment: You could run a EXPLAIN [query] and parse out the table column

Comment: But if you are writing the query, how do you not know the table names...?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not explain that point. The user will inform the query

Comment: If the query is generated by programming code based on user input, populate your array at the same time as you build your query string.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be tough using regex - unless you know your queries are all consistently following the same standard. Here's an option using [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html).

```
$tables = [];
$query = "EXPLAIN SELECT first_name FROM users INNER JOIN roles ON roles.id = users.id_rolesWHERE roles.name = 'admin'";
$q = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $tables[] = $r['table'];
}
print_r(array_unique($tables));
```